# Google app script to construct URL from spreadsheet values and execute it

Tags: google-apps-script

I am basically creating a CRM upon a spreadsheet, that is being populated by a google form.
Everytime there is a new entry, I would like to notify an external server by calling a postback URL.
So URL parameters must be taken from the spreadsheet cells of the new entry (the last row), and then executed.
Something like this:
http://www.myserver.com/script.php?value1=[lastrow.cell1]&value2=[lastrow.cell2]....

Then I need to call the URL.

How would you code it?

I Guess this script can be triggered on new line creation on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Correct`````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. About `execute it` and `I need to call the URL.`, what result do you want? 2. About `new line creation on the spreadsheet`, how is the new line created in your situation? For example, the new line is created with the manual of user or a script or a Google form?

Comment: 1. The URL execute a script on my server, so it just has to be run (like a click).  2. From a Google form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl) to automate the process of submitting a form to your spreadsheet and then sending an HTTP request to your server containing the form's values.

This is an example of how you would do it (Adapt it to your own form's questions):

```
// Installable trigger function
function formSubmit(e) {

  // Take values from the form submitted
  var channelResp = e.namedValues["Channel"];
  var question1 = e.namedValues["Question 1"];

  // Get values form Parameters sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var parametersSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Parameters");
  var parametersArray = parametersSheet.getRange("A2:B4").getValues();

  try {
     // Verify if the value in channel was well submitted and search for it
     var [channel, variable] = parametersArray.find(element => element[0] == channelResp);
     // Build the params with your form's answers 
     var params = `value1=${question1}&value2=${variable}`;
     // Add the params to your url 
     var url = `http://www.myserver.com/script.php?${params}`;
     // Make the request
     UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  } catch(e) {
    // Throw an exception if the value in channel was not well-submitted
    // Or there was an HTTP error
    Logger.log(e);
  }

}
```

Notice that `e` represents the [Event Object Form Submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit). Now, for setting up the installable trigger, do the following:

1) Go to your Apps Script project

2) Click Edit->Current project's triggers

3) Click "+ Add Trigger"

4) Select :

- Choose which function to run -> *Function Name*
- Select event source-> From spreadsheet
- Select event type -> On form submit

5) Click Save

### Restrictions

- Keep in mind the [Installable Trigger restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) will not work if you're executing your server as a local server because it will not be able to reach it.

Comment: This is a good clue, but in order to construct the URL I cannot take the values from the form. 
I must take them from the spreadsheet (which is populated by form answers) because  I have to vlookup some of them.
Actually I could construct the URL directly on the spread sheet like this:
`CONCATENATE("http://myserver.com/scripts/sale.php?var1=",$N2,"&var2=",VLOOKUP(F2,Parametri!$E$2:$F$27,2,false),"&var3=1642c2f4")`
and then calling it from the app script.
But it is definitely more elegant if I construct it on the app script dynamically.

How would you achieve it?

Comment: So let me see if I understood well. You need the form's answers to build something with info already in your Spreadsheet? It could be easier to picture if you share a spreadsheet with some dummy data please. You will use VLOOKUP to search for some match values that already exist in your Spreadsheet?

Comment: Here it's a form example: https://forms.gle/LvEcdB2CvX4XXQZT9

Here's the spreadsheet populated with forms' answers: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PgbQAD7lMR4cGyAiNS5lcN6mNs8PzIuIoi320Asz0EM/edit?usp=sharing

in the second sheet there is a small table where I turn the field 'channel' into the relative 'var' which I need to use in the URL.
One way is like you suggested, to trigger the function on form submit - but you still need to vlookup that value from the spreadsheet. The other is to trigger the function on 'new line creation' upon the spreadsheet, still vlookuping the value.

Comment: The URL should be something like: 
CONCATENATE("http://myserver.com/scripts/sale.php?var1=",Form Responses 1!A2,"&var2=",VLOOKUP(Form Responses 1!D2,Parameters!$a$2:$B$5,2,false)

Comment: I modified my code. I left a generic ```question1``` var, so you can take that value later as you want

Comment: I get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined
    at formSubmit(Code:5:23)

Comment: Did you configure the Installable trigger as I described in my answer? Also, don't run the script directly, otherwise the ```e``` object will be empty and you will get that kind of error you're getting. It will run automatically every time you submit the form linked to your spreadsheet

Comment: Yes, all configured as you said.
So you say thet the only way to try is to fill a form and submit it.
I did that, but got no http request at the server.

Comment: By Clicking in your Apps Script Project on `View` -> `Executions` you can see the logs of each runtime.It will help you to see the error

Comment: I get this: Info
TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Comment: any clue Alberto?

Comment: ```parametersArray.find(element => element[0] == channelResp)``` is not finding an element in the ```parametersArray``` which matches the ```channelResp``` (value extracted from the form's answer), therefore it's returning ***null*** and ```[channel, variable]``` can't be null. That's the reason you are getting that error. Try using ***Channel*** as your example sheet with the values one, two or three.

Comment: I solved with this: 

for (nn = 0; nn < parametersArray.length; nn++){
    if (parametersArray[nn][0].toString().toUpperCase() == channelResp.toString().toUpperCase()) {
      var variable = parametersArray[nn][1];

Now everything is working like a charme. Thank you so much!!!